# Simple string tokenizer wrapper

Tags: c++, design-patterns, strings

Is this orthogonal?

```
#ifndef TOKENIZER_H
#define TOKENIZER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class StringTokenizer
{
private:
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;
        unsigned int index;

public:
    StringTokenizer(std::string const & str, const char delim)
    {
        index = 0;
        // Populate the token vector...
        std::istringstream stream(str);
        std::string token;
        while (std::getline(stream, token, delim))
        {
            tokens.push_back(token);
        }
    }
    ~StringTokenizer(void) { };

    bool HasMoreTokens() { return index < tokens.size(); };
    std::string NextToken() { return TokenAtIndex(index++); };
    std::string PreviousToken() { return TokenAtIndex(index--); };
    std::string TokenAtIndex(int x) 
    {
        std::string token = "";
        try 
        {
            token = tokens.at(x);
        }
        catch (const std::out_of_range& range_error)
        {
            std::cerr << "[!!] Out of Range: " << range_error.what() << std::endl;
        }
        return token;
    }
    void Clear() { index = 0; };
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor is nigh-identical to [this up-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/49942) for splitting a string.

The rest of the class doesn't add much value: IMO the vector provides the same API as your class and more besides; so a user might prefer to have the vector than to have your StringTokenizer instance which wraps/encapsulates/hides the vector.

`vector.at` returns a const reference, instead of returning by value: perhaps your methods should too.

Comment: Thanks! I tend to obsess over details, and overlook more obvious design issues, like "IS THIS THING ACTUALLY USEFUL?!"

Comment: You can actually go a step further, and use something like `std::istringstream i(input); std::vector<std::string>{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(i), std::istream_iterator<std::string>()};` to create the vector\from the tokens. Also see [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tokenizer/).

Answer (score 3):

Seems like overkill.
The reason I would use the class is this:

```
std::string      data(getData());
StringTokenizer  token(data, ' ');

while(token.HasMoreTokens())
{
    std::string value = token.NextToken();
    // STUFF
}
```

Which seems OK. But when I compare this with the way I would normally do it.

```
std::string       data(getData());
std::stringstream token(data);

std::string       value;
while(std::getline(token, value, ';'))
{
    // STUFF
}
```

I don't see any real advantage. Why would I use a non tested class in place where I can easily use standard functions?